# Report Configuration changes

Tags: functions, type-conversion, sql-variant-property

I created a stored procedure that I got on Erin Stellato's course on Pluralsight to report if there are any configuration changes on the server as a nightly job as follows:

```
CREATEPROCEDURE dbo.usp_SysConfigReport1 
(
    @RecentDate DATETIME,
    @OlderDate DATETIME
)

AS

BEGIN;
    IF
    @RecentDate IS NULL
    OR @OlderDate IS NULL
    BEGIN;
    RAISERROR('Input parameters cannot be NULL', 16, 1);
RETURN;
END;
SELECT  
        @@SERVERNAME ServerName,
        CaptureDate,
        [O].[Name], 
        [O].[Value] AS "OlderValue", 
        [O].[ValueInUse] AS"OlderValueInUse",
        [R].[Value] AS "RecentValue", 
        [R].[ValueInUse] AS "RecentValueInUse"

    FROM [dbo].[ConfigData] O

    JOIN

        (SELECT [ConfigurationID], [Value], [ValueInUse]

        FROM [dbo].[ConfigData]

        WHERE [CaptureDate] = @RecentDate) R on [O].[ConfigurationID] = [R].[ConfigurationID]

    WHERE [O].[CaptureDate] = @OlderDate

    AND (([R].[Value] <> [O].[Value]) OR ([R].[ValueInUse] <> [O].[ValueInUse]))

END


--------
--Capture the capture dates into #temp table1
SELECT  DISTINCT
[CaptureDate]
INTO #CapturedDates
FROM [dbo].[ConfigData]
ORDER BY [CaptureDate]

    --Create temp table2
CREATE TABLE #CapturedDates2 (
         ServerName NVARCHAR(20)
        ,[CaptureDate] DATETIMEOFFSET
        ,Name NVARCHAR(1000)
        ,[OlderValue] INT
        ,[OlderValueInUse] INT
        ,[RecentValue] INT
        ,RecentValueInUse INT   
)


------Inserting into Temp2 gin=ving error message as below

DECLARE @MINCapturedDate DATETIME
DECLARE @MAXCapturedDate DATETIME

SELECT @MINCapturedDate =(SELECT CAST(MIN([CaptureDate]) AS DATETIME) FROM #CapturedDates)
SELECT @MAXCapturedDate =(SELECT CAST(MAX([CaptureDate]) AS DATETIME) FROM #CapturedDates)

INSERT INTO #CapturedDates2
EXEC SYSDBA.dbo.usp_SysConfigReport1 @MINCapturedDate ,@MAXCapturedDate
```

But it gives me the following error message:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure usp_SysConfigReport1, Line 19
>   Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to int is not allowed.
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

EDIT: Include definition of ConfigData

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConfigData] 
   ( [ConfigurationID] [INT] NOT NULL, 
     [Name] [NVARCHAR](35) NOT NULL, 
     [Value] [SQL_VARIANT] NULL, 
     [ValueInUse] [SQL_VARIANT] NULL, 
     [CaptureDate] [DATETIME] NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Could you add the table definition with datatypes for the dbo.ConfigData table?

Comment: Here is the definition of the config data table:USE [sysdba]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ConfigData]') AND type IN (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConfigData](
 [ConfigurationID] [INT] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [NVARCHAR](35) NOT NULL,
 [Value] [SQL_VARIANT] NULL,
 [ValueInUse] [SQL_VARIANT] NULL,
 [CaptureDate] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [dbo].[ConfigData] TO  SCHEMA OWNER 
GO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the definition you provided for [dbo].[ConfigData], both `Value` and `ValueInUse` are defined as `SQL_VARIANT` data types.  The error message you are receiving is:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure usp_SysConfigReport1, Line 19
>   Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to int is not allowed.
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

So `Value` and `ValueInUse` are `SQL_VARIANT` (as also are the derived values for `OlderValue`, `OlderValueInUse`, `RecentValue`, and `RecentValueInUse`) but you want to use them as `INT`.

The error message is saying that you need to change the `SQL_VARIANT` into INT by using the `CONVERT` function.  An example of selecting a `SQL_VARIANT` and turning it into an `INT`.

```
SELECT CONVERT (int, Value) FROM [dbo].[ConfigData]
```

The `CONVERT` changes the datatype (if possible) from `SQL_VARIANT` to `INT`.

Just make sure to `CONVERT` to the proper data type and all should be well.

Comment: Thanks a million, I spotted the data type, the moment I scripted out the table definition. Thanks for shedding light into this.